# SUM HH.MM.SS IN SQL OR AS400 DATABASE

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

I want to calculate total working hour from the table field as below:

table name : Attendance
field name : working_hours

```
select SUM(working_hours) from Attendance
```

In working_hours field i have data in format

```
empcode working_hours
123456  08.45.00
123456  10.06.00
123456  10.00.00
123456  09.06.00
```

I want this in Total hours like (17.50.00)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Column working_hours data type?

Comment: What is `working_hours`?  It looks like text, so you'll first have to translate it into something numeric in order to sum it.  To do that, you'll have to determine what each part represents.  hours.minutes.seconds?  hours.hundredthsOfAnHour.hundredthsOfAMinute? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

the `hour` and `minute` sql functions will return the hour and minutes of the working_hours time field. You can sum up hours and minutes.  Then divide total minutes by 60 to get the hours the minutes add up to.  And the `mod` function returns the remainder of minutes divided by 60.

```
select  sum(hour(a.working_hours)) +        
        sum(minute(a.working_hours)) / 60 , 
          mod(minute(a.working_hours),60)   
from     attendance a
```